# How should you setup databases in Superset for seamless deploy between dev and prod?

Tags: apache-superset

At the moment, if you export a dashboard from dev, and import it into prod, it'll overwrite the shared database connection with the dev one.

If you remove the database connection from the export and import it, it then fails to import any of the charts. (Silently).

So how are people handling this?

Is it necessary to create a process to munge the exported zip so that it can be deployed to prod?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this lies in your database connections.

When you first setup superset if you setup your connections in the same ORDER then when you import your dashboards from prod to dev it all works fine.

This is with 1.5.x and 2.0.x as well.